# REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Parent]: [Parent]

Tags: pdf, salesforce, attachment, visualforce, apex

I am trying to save an attachment. The attachment is saved but whenever I open the VFpage it has an error of:

Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Parent]: [Parent]

I have 2 VFPages in doing this. One is the VFPage rendered as PDF and the other one is just a reference for saving attachment and for loading VFPage rendered as PDF. Does anyone here have an idea on how to fix this error?

This is VFPage for reference

Here is the Apex Classes:

```
public class attachPDFDocument{

public String parentId{get;set;}
public String curPage = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

public String vrsn = 'AttachmentV';
public Integer vrsion;

public String attName {get;set;}
public String attNames {get;set;}
public String attNameSubString;
public String attNameSubStrings;
public Integer attCount;
public Integer attachCount;   

public attachPDFDocument(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {    

}

public PageReference pdfLoad(){   
      List<Attachment> pdfAttach = new List <Attachment>();
      PageReference pdf = Page.PDFAttachment;   

      List<Attachment> att = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachment where ParentId = :curPage Order by Name DESC]; //getting all attachments  

      //String attachName = att.Name;


      if(att.size() <= 0){             
          vrsion = 1;
      }else if(att.size() <= 9){

          Attachment attachmentPDF = att[0];
          attName = attachmentPDF.Name;  // yung latest Version
          attNameSubString = attName.subString(35,36);
          vrsion = Integer.valueOf(attNameSubString) + 1;     
      }else if(att.size() > 9){                                   

          List<Attachment> attachPDFDoc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachment where ParentId = :curPage AND Name LIKE '___________' ORDER BY Name DESC LIMIT 1]; //getting all attachments with length is 41                  
          Attachment docpdf= attachPDFDoc[0];
          String pdfdoc = docpdf.Name;                
          attNameSubString = pdfdoc.subString(35,37);            
          vrsion = Integer.valueOf(attNameSubString) + 1; 
       }else if(att.size() > 99){                                   

          List<Attachment> attachPDFDoc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachment where ParentId = :curPage AND Name LIKE '___________' ORDER BY Name DESC LIMIT 1]; //getting all attachments with length is 41                  
          Attachment docpdf= attachPDFDoc[0];
          String pdfdoc = docpdf.Name;                
          attNameSubString = pdfdoc.subString(35,38);            
          vrsion = Integer.valueOf(attNameSubString) + 1; 
       }

      Attachment attach = new Attachment();
      Blob body;

      try {
          body= pdf.getContent();            
      } catch (VisualforceException e) {
          body= Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage());
      } 

      attach.Body = body ;           
      attach.IsPrivate = false;        
      attach.ContentType = '/application/pdf';
      attach.ParentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
      attach.Name = vrsn + vrsion + '.pdf';

      insert attach;
      return pdf;           
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged this line ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); to see that it's returning an actual ID?  Check that attach.parentid is not null.